# Deletion reasons for a Linux file system question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

A basic question, [What is a directory entry? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164031/what-is-a-directory-entry/30164716), was closed because it was flagged off-topic. I understand the closure as I believe this may be more appropriate for the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange site. A similar question on the Linux & Unix site is: [what is directory entry?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186992/what-is-directory-entry) (which I did not know when answering at that time).

Surprisingly, the question was deleted. Which I do not understand why. In case the reason for deletion was same as the reason for closure, then it should have been migrated.

I answered this question for the following reasons.

1. I believe that the question demanded an answer with respect to how a directory is handled in the [Virtual File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system) layer in the kernel, and not the userspace hierarchical structure.
2. Searching for "linux filesystem layout", "linux filesystem architecture", "linux directory layout", "linux directory structure" or any other possible terms come up with results which explains the directory hierarchy (/bin,/opt,/lib etc.), in the user space, and does not reflect how exactly the kernel seeks and opens a directory or a file when we perform a `cat /my/math/my_file.c` or similar type of file or directory access. Hence, I thought this question could add some value to distinguish between these two aspects.

It would be interested to understand why the question was deleted.

Comment: Related Über-Meta: [Is “Too old to migrate” a good reason NOT to migrate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136537/is-too-old-to-migrate-a-good-reason-not-to-migrate)

Comment: @yivi: I agree that migrating is not a good idea for this as it is too old and does not add much value.

Comment: Not all closed questions need to be deleted. I voted to undelete.

Comment: Sorry about the comments you received, by the way.  You don't deserve those remarks.

Comment: @Makoto: Thanks. These comments are not a problem in this case, it was the closure of a possibly good (though ambiguous) question was a bit sad. Unfortunately, I failed to get any effective feedback from the commenter which I could use to improve the answer.

Comment: Looking at the timelines for the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30164031/timeline) and [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30164716/timeline), and ignoring the meta effect yesterday, there's no evidence that either the question or the answer were providing value. (Assuming there is any validity in the communities' views & votes stats, ofc.)

Answer (score 5):

I suppose I'll go a bit simpler on why the question should remain deleted.

There's some ambiguity from the perspective of the question as to what is actually being asked.  Is the OP looking for what it  means to have an element inside of a directory in Unix, or are they looking for how files are handled with respect to a directory of a file system?

The OP will not help us disambiguate.  The last time they were here was when they posted that question.

Comment: I fully agree that the question is ambiguous. My interpretation was based on the part of the question: * 'directory entries' in the context of the Linux operating system * . In general directory entries are referred to the entries in directory files, as the term was in quotes. Although this is an assumption from my side.

I can agree with your answer.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. I believe that the question demanded an answer with respect to how a directory is handled in the Virtual File System layer in the kernel, and not the userspace hierarchical structure.

I disagree, because of what the asker wrote:

> Also, please use simple terminology as I have limited knowledge of computing.

Someone with limited knowledge of computing has probably never heard of a "virtual file system".

This also invalidates your second point I think. Sure, the answer might contain useful information, but it completely missed the point of the question.

Comment: For the off-topic point, I partially agree, at this can also be a part of SO community. The answer part is different and is another thing. But, for a high-level introduction with a few pointers to start getting the picture can be helpful.